# Problems with multiple update in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have mongo structure like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51596b7e469b9c3816000001"),
        "company" : {
                "_id" : "ade2fd0ec9b8b5e9152e0155",
                "title" : "LO3426546457"
        },
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51596cef469b9c3816000008"),
        "company" : {
                "_id" : "ade2fd0ec9b8b5e9152e0155",
                "title" : "LO3426546457"
        },
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51596cc3469b9c3816000007"),
        "company" : {
                "_id" : "ade2fd0ec9b8b5e9152e0155",
                "title" : "LO3426546457"
        }        
}
```

And I want to change all 'title' fields for objects with a specific '_id'.
I do like this:

```
Collections.UsersCollection.update({
    'company._id': 'ade2fd0ec9b8b5e9152e0155'
}, {
    $set: {
        'company': { _id: 'ade2fd0ec9b8b5e9152e0155', title: 'blablabla' }
        // I also tried: 'company.title': 'blablabla'
    }
}, false, true);
```

And after execution that code in Node.js (I use node-mongodb-native), mongo updates **only one** document.

But if I do that command at Mongo Shell (mongo.exe), everything works fine and updates all documents.

What's the problem?

Comment: You said that command works in mongo shell, but where it doesn't work?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It doesn't work in my Node.js code. I use this module: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Answer (score 2):

By default mongo updates only a single document. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Use multi option for multiple document update.

Comment: Being optional parameter, I think your true might be interpreted as true for upsert. I will give a try with explicit  {multi: true}, if you have not tried yet.

Comment: I try that code, but nothing changed.
`Collections.UsersCollection.update({
                'company._id': id
            }, {
                $set: {
                    'company.title': title
                }
            }, {upsert: false}, {multi: true});`

Comment: You should pass your options as a [single object](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#update-update-and-insert-upsert) `Collections.UsersCollection.update({ 'company._id': id }, { $set: { 'company.title': title } }, {upsert: false, multi: true})`

Answer (score 0):

By default collection.update() updates only a single document, if you need to update multiple docs you have to add the {multi:1} parameter before the callback function.